# swagger documentation, generating controller path wrongly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, swagger, swagger-ui

I am documenting the API's of my ROR application using Swagger. This is my initializer file:

```
class Swagger::Docs::Config
def self.transform_path(path, api_version)
  # Make a distinction between the APIs and API documentation paths.
  "/apidocs/#{path}" 
  end
end
Swagger::Docs::Config.register_apis({
'1.0' => {
  controller_base_path: '',
  api_file_path: 'public/apidocs',
  base_path: 'http://localhost:3000',
  clean_directory: true
}})
```

when i run the rake task,the api-docs.json wil generate for swagger GUI.

```
    {
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/apidocs/api/v1/users.{format}",
      "description": "UserS"
    }]}
```

But the respective JSON generated for users.json,the path is not coming out correctly.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "resourcePath": "users",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "api/v1/users",
      "operations": [
        {
          "summary": "Fetches all User items",
          "notes": "This lists all the active users",
          "parameters": [
            {.....} ]}]}]}
```

Instead of `"path": "api/v1/users"`, I need to get `"path": "/api/v1/users"`,

Comment: do you mean instead of `"path": "/apidocs/api/v1/users.{format}"`?

Comment: No,the path which is generating is not correct."/" is missing.so the path wont be correct to send API calls.now am editing all generated JSON manually.